# Selenium - Set http proxy to the webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I've been trying to use a [http proxy](https://www.hidemyass.com/de-de/proxy) with Selenium.
What I have so far is:

```
PROXY = "46.4.29.2:80"
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy": PROXY,
    "ftpProxy": PROXY,
    "sslProxy": PROXY,
    "noProxy": None,
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",
    "class": "org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
    "autodetect": False
}
```

However, it simply doesn't work and throws:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I use a library called selenium-wire https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/ which can be used for both authenticated and non-authenticated proxies. Here is the documentation reference for proxy use https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire#proxies

I have made a short snippet of code that uses a public proxy to go to google.com

```
import seleniumwire
from seleniumwire import webdriver

options = {'proxy': 
{
    'http' : 'http://45.152.188.246:3128'}
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options)

driver.get("https://google.com/")
```

Here is also a method that would work without the need for selenium-wire.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=45.152.188.246:3128')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://google.com/")
```

Comment: However, is it possible to use an http proxy like https://www.hidemyass.com/de-de/proxy with that? If yes, could you please tell me how?

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I could just put the proxy link and then the link I wanted to get. Thank you!